# AWS Cognito - MFA setup

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, multi-factor-authentication

I use the JavaScript AWS SDK for MFA setup and have 2 issues:
First, I update phone number (phone_number attribute with updateUserAttributes method).

It updates but returns empty object instead of (according to docs):

```
{
    "CodeDeliveryDetailsList": [ 
    { 
        "AttributeName": "string",
        "DeliveryMedium": "string",
        "Destination": "string"
    }
    ]
}
```

Second, I am trying to send user a verification code with `getAttributeVerificationCode` with the following payload:

```
const params = { 
  AccessToken: auth.accessToken,    
  AttributeName: 'phone_number'
}
```

and I am getting

```
CustomMessage failed with error
Cannot read property identity of undefined
```

as error. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

For the ones who come across same problem, we could solve it by using cognitoUser.updateAttributes instead of cognitoidentityserviceprovider.updateUserAttributes contrary to the official docs. AWS, especially cognito is premature and lack of docs is another issue for the ones who are considering to use.

Answer (score 0):

AWS is expecting strings, maybe the token is getting passed incorrectly here...

```
const params =    {
   "AccessToken": auth.accessToken.toString(),
   "UserAttributes": [ 
      { 
         "Name": "phone number",
         "Value": "(555)555-5555"
      }
   ]
}
```

And here...

```
const params = {
   "AccessToken": auth.accessToken.toString(),
   "AttributeName": "phone number"
}
```